# Send multiple tone generators to a mixer and play the output of the mixer

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

- Using NAudio Library
- I have seen the following link:
  https://markheath.net/post/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio (don't fully understand the detail)
- I am able to play generated tones one after the other.

What I don't understand is how to combine multiple tone generators/sources into a mixer and play the output of that mixer as shown below:
[image]

I'm missing some fundamental understanding of the process here I think, so any pointers or further detail would really help me move forward.

Creating the mixer:

```
WaveMixerStream32 mixer = new WaveMixerStream32();
mixer.AddInputStream(GenerateUpperSine(args[0]));
mixer.AddInputStream(GenerateLowerSine(args[1]));
```

Creating the Sine Generators:

```
private static WaveStream GenerateUpperSine(string frequency){
  var outFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 1);
  const int durationInSecods = 5;
  var UpperFreq = new SignalGenerator();
  {
    Gain = 0.2,
    Frequency = Double.Parse(frequency),
    Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sin
  }
  var sp = UpperFreq.ToWaveProvider16();
  byte{} data = new Byte[outFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * durationInSeconds];
  var bytesRead = new sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
  return new RawSourceWaveStream(new MemoryStream(data), outFormat);
}
```

The GenerateLowerSine function is an exact duplicate of the upper one, just with some variables changed.

Calling this application from the command line as follows:

```
c:\path\to\exe\my.exe 1000 750
```

I have some code which I can add to the generation code which plays the tones as expected, one after the other. This may reside within the function and is as follows:

```
var wo = new WaveOutEvent();
wo.Init(UpperFreq);
wo.Play();
```

This indicates the basic functionality is working, at least in part.

What I believe I am missing is either:

- how to send the output of the tone generators to the mixer and then initiate the playback from the output of the mixer

**or**

- possibly connect the output of the mixer to a WaveOut device and send
  the audio/data from the tone generators to the inputs of the mixer

Perhaps it is something else though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.